# Why are @keyframes animations not working with Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js, css-animations

I'm trying to make a link flash when the user loads the site. However, the animation doesn't work in Vue.

I tried the same code without Vue in a seperate file and it worked just fine.

This is the element which should flash. (The class 'flash' shows up in the DOM. It seems like it's not a problem with my JS)

```html
<a href="/test/" :class="isFlashing ? 'flash' : ''">
  <h2>Test</h2>
</a>
```

The animation in CSS:

```css
.flash {
  -webkit-animation: flashing 0.5s infinite;
  animation: flashing 0.5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flashing {
  0% {
    color: white;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes flashing {
  0% {
    color: white;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

And the style for the h2 element itself:

```css
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 93%;

  color: white;

  margin-left: 7%;
}
```

I expected the link to flash infinitely, but nothing happened. It just stays white. As said before, the animations works when Vue is not loaded.

Comment: Vue doesn't block keyframes/animation. have you declared isFlashing? maybe try this without conditional class?

Comment: I already tried it without a conditional class. It also didn't work. So you can't see any mistake in the code itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `h2` styles: `color: white;` will override the animation color rules.

Either remove `color: white;` from the `h2` styles, or add the class `flash` to the `h2` element, instead of the `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem today. The problem is the parsing in "style scoped" and "style" tags on a .vue file does not support keyframe with % in it.

A 'hackish' workaround is to just include a style tag in your template with just the css containing those @keyframe lines.

```
<template>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/assets/keyframe_animation.css"/>

  your other template html here
</template>

<style scoped>
regular/other css here
</style>
```

This way you avoid the css needing to get parsed (however this has drawbacks like that css will also not be minified etc.) But it does start to work again that way.